# get multiple column names (header) in table associated with particular value in to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

i need to get multiple column names (header) in table associated with particular value in to a cell

as i explained, i need to get the heading names corresponding to value "n" to column E.

[image]
i used the formula

```
 =INDEX((A$1:D$1),MATCH("n",A2:D2,0))
```

here. but it only give one column name.

i am open to vba scripts also. but i think it doesn't need vba. just improve the the above formula, may be. i tried and failed. any help. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are really "open" to vba, I'll use one simple UDF like:

```
Function HeatherNames(rg As Range, rf As String) As String
For Each cell In rg
    If cell = rf Then HeatherNames = HeatherNames & Cells(1, cell.Column).Value & "-"
Next cell
HeatherNames = Left(HeatherNames, Len(HeatherNames) - 1)
End Function
```

you can use it in the column E `=HeatherNames(A2:D2;"n") now you can select the arg.1 (range) and type (or referring to another cell) the arg.2

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand the script you mentioned. i tried. but its not working

Comment: sorry. i did something wrong. now it worked. but it only gives right value for first rows

Comment: @hafisjamal if you are happy for the solution please mark as answered your tread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Excel 2010 or later, in E2:

`=IF(COLUMNS($A:A)>COUNTIF($A2:$D2,"n"),"",INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$D2)/($A2:$D2="n"),COLUMNS($A:A))))`

Copy to the right and down as required.

It would actually be slightly more efficient (and certainly if your dataset in reality is quite large) to have the initial `IF` clause held within its own cell, such that it is calculated for each row only once, rather than for each instance of the formula within that row. So a better set-up would be, in E2:

`=COUNTIF($A2:$D2,"n")`

copied down. Then, in F2:

`=IF(COLUMNS($A:A)>$E2,"",INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$D2)/($A2:$D2="n"),COLUMNS($A:A))))`

copied to the right and down again.

Regards

Comment: hi. thanks for the response.your formula gives same result as the one i explained .thing is i need result in different way. l need the headers  (A,B) in cell E2( means i need all the column names which has values 'n' in column E

Comment: Then I think you need to change your original post so that it reflects your actual needs.